# How to make my bibliography an appendix?

Tags: bibliographies, appendices

I'm trying to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
% ...
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\appendix
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

I want my bibliography be titled as `"A. References"`, as all other appendixes. But it's still titled as `"References"`. What to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the bibliography is set as a `\section*` You'll need to redefine the bibliography sectioning command `\bibsection`

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{\refname}}
```

Or something like that. Can't check it works right now...

Comment: For the article class, it should be `\refname` instead of `\bibname`.

Comment: @lockstep Thanks. I've edited it now. I still haven't actually checked the above works. I'm stupidly busy, I don't even know why I'm on SE at all...

Answer (score 3):

With biblatex, you can define the references as a section similar to any section. You can also easily add text between the section title and the references.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}          
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=nty,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,
hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=false]{biblatex}      
\bibliography{mem}            
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}      
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
ploplo\cite{report}
\section{Section 2}
ploplo
\appendix
\section{References}
blabla
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty]
\end{document}
```

with mem.bib as follows:

```
@TechReport{report,
  author =      {Name, first name},
  title =       {Report title},
  institution = {School},
  year =        {2010}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you shouldn't: The bibliography is an unnumbered section/chapter by aeons of printing custom.

Many of the default (La)TeX decisions seem nonsensical or counterintuitive, but digging deeper you find that they have a very sound reason, or at least stem from a long tradition. Don't forget that the principal function of the formatting of the text is to make reading easy (that includes catering to well-worn routine), never to startle the reader.